# What does class.weight in {e1071} do?

Tags: r, svm

I have been looking around for documentation on what the class.weight argument do in the e1071 package in R. Is it assigning different costs for the misclassification of the labels?

This link also suggests that class.weight is used as input to limit the impact of disproportionate class size https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/e1071/vignettes/svmdoc.pdf

Comment: What are you missing in : "a named vector of weights for the different classes, used for asymmetric class sizes. Not all factor levels have to be supplied (default weight: 1). All components have to be named." 
But indeed this can be used to simulate cost functions.

Comment: Hey @CAFEBABE could you elaborate on what this means? Does it try to weight the cost based on the label and the weight specified? That is my impression from libsvm documentation

Answer (score 0):

I found this PDF from Joao Neto:http://www.di.fc.ul.pt/~jpn/r/svm/svm.html

Looks like class.weights does assign different penalty costs for misclassifications when we are working with soft margins.